# Django + Nginx home click issue

Tags: python, django

I am using Django with Gunicorn, Virtualenv, Supervisor, and Nginx.
When I've moved to Nginx, clicking my blog 'home' URL shows 'mydjangoblogserver' and the result is not found, but any other functions are working fine except 'click home'.

I think that Nginx and Gunicorn are resposible to the problem.

ngnix.conf:

```
user root;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream mydjangoblogserver {
        server unix:/home/blog/dev/DjangoBlog/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server{
        server_name www.xxx.club;
        root /home/blog/dev/DjangoBlog;
        listen 80;
        keepalive_timeout 70;
        location /collectedstatic/ {
            expires max;
            alias /home/blog/dev/DjangoBlog/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                #proxy_pass http://xxx.club;
                proxy_pass http://mydjangoblogserver;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

django_start file:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="djangoblog" # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/blog/dev/DjangoBlog # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/blog/dev/DjangoBlog/run/gunicorn.sock # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=root # the user to run as
GROUP=root # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3 # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=DjangoBlog.settings # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=DjangoBlog.wsgi # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/blog/dev/python3/bin/activate
export django_settings_module=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
#export pythonpath=$djangodir:$pythonpath
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# create the run directory if it doesn't exist
#rundir=$(dirname $sockfile)
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
echo $RUNDIR
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# start your django unicorn
# programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
# exec /var/www/dev/python3/bin/gunicorn ${django_wsgi_module}:application \
echo ${django_wsgi_module}
exec /home/blog/dev/python3/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
--log-level=debug \
--log-file=/home/blog/dev/DjangoBlog/gunicorn.log
```

supervisor.conf:

```
[program:djangoblog]
command = /home/blog/dev/DjangoBlog/bin/django_start
user = root
autostart=true
autorestart=true

redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /root/logs/blog/robot.log
stderr_logfile=/root/logs/blog/err.log
```

Comment: What does the "Home" button in your app point to?

Comment: main page, like when you  use google searching some texts,and you want to go back and search other, you will click ’Google' Logo to come back..

Comment: Yes, but what does it literally do? What's the `<a href="...">` or whatever?

Comment: here is <a href="http://mydjangoblogserver/" title="mytitle" rel="home">mytitle</a>           and http://mydjangoblogserver/ is automatically created.

Comment: Right. Your Nginx config mounts your application at `/`, not at `/mydjangoblogserver/`; unless your app has a route for `mydjangoblogserver`, that's obviously going to 404.

Comment: what's best way to modify this?